# How to auto calculate numRepartition while using spark dataframe write

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

When I tried to write dataframe to Hive Parquet Partitioned Table

```
df.write.partitionBy("key").mode("append").format("hive").saveAsTable("db.table")
```

It will create a lots of blocks in HDFS, each of the block only have small size of data.

I understand how it goes as each spark sub-task will create a block, then write data to it.

I also understand, num of blocks will increase the Hadoop performance, but it will also decrease the performance after reaching a threshold.

If i want to auto set numPartition, does anyone have a good idea?

```
numPartition = ??? // auto calc basing on df size or something
df.repartition("numPartition").write
  .partitionBy("key")
  .format("hive")
  .saveAsTable("db.table")
```

Comment: Its almost as if you've asked `How to master Apache-Spark?`. Choosing the *right level of parallelism* is the crux of leveraging `Spark`'s full capabilities among other things. [Here](https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/sparksqlshufflepartitions_draft.html)'s a good start; it boils down to amount of data you are processing: no of columns, type of columns, no of rows etc. It will take time and effort (hit and trials) to arrive at a metric for `numPartition`s. I start with no of rows & size of data (GBs) to predict it, and then fine-tune it from there

Comment: Your blog is amazing, I did implement some of your best practice in df transformation. Your methodology looks great, but in my case I have tons of offline data pipeline, is it a good choice if I ignore the "repartition" part and optimize it afterwards?

Comment: **@Eric Yiwei Liu**, the said blog is from [Umberto Griffo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6271839/umberto-griffo). Its completely acceptable if you want to take things step-by-step, viz. skipping `repartition` now and re-visiting it later. In fact IMHO when your'e dealing with complex frameworks like `Spark`, its better to take this route: quickly hack up a *preliminary solution* and then gradually working up from there to improve it. Recall that **Premature Optimization is the Root of all Evil**

Comment: @y2k-shubham Absolutely positive, compress CDH warning is working well so far,  i think it's alway a good feature for future spark, let us more focus on development.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you want to have an extra repartition step when you are already using `partitionBy(key)`- your data would be partitioned based on the key.

Generally, you could re-partition by a column value, that's a common scenario, helps in operations like reduceByKey, filtering based on column value etc. For example,

```
val birthYears = List(
  (2000, "name1"),
  (2000, "name2"),
  (2001, "name3"),
  (2000, "name4"),
  (2001, "name5")
)
val df = birthYears.toDF("year", "name")

df.repartition($"year")
```

Answer (score -1):

By Default spark will create 200 Partitions for shuffle operations. so, 200 files/blocks (if the file size is less) will be written to HDFS.

Configure the number of partitions to be created after shuffle based on your data in Spark using below configuration:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", <Number of paritions>)
```

ex: `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5")`, so Spark will create 5 partitions and 5 files will be written to HDFS.